# Error trying to install Squarespace server in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions, nodejs, npm

I've been trying to get a local SquareSpace server running on a VM (Ubuntu 20.04), following the instructions in https://developers.squarespace.com/get-started

When I run npm install -g @squarespace/server I return the following error

```
> @squarespace/server@1.6.2 copyrunscript /usr/lib/node_modules/@squarespace/server
> node scripts/copyfile.js build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat darwin:build/distributions/local-developer/bin/osx-local-developer win32:build/distributions/local-developer/bin/win-local-developer.bat linux:build/distributions/local-developer/bin/linux-local-developer build/distributions/local-developer/bin/local-developer

copying build/distributions/local-developer/bin/linux-local-developer to build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat
npm ERR! dest /usr/bin/squarespace-server
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat' -> '/usr/bin/squarespace-server'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat' -> '/usr/bin/squarespace-server'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat' -> '/usr/bin/squarespace-server'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     path: '../lib/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat',
npm ERR!     dest: '/usr/bin/squarespace-server'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/bin/squarespace-server'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Can anyone give me any indication as to what must be done to resolve this? I've already tried running the command with sudo before, but it returned a permissions error and all the answers I've searched online indicated that running sudo npm install is something to avoid.